# In Angular2, how to add a CSS class to an element when the link is clicked without using RouterLinkActive?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am creating nav menu using

```
<li *ngFor="let child of children">
  <a (click)="navChanged(child.name)">
    <div> {{child.name}} </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Now I want to add `class="active"` to the child.name that is active(clicked) and I am not using routes.

Comment: please try property binding [has.class]="ifClicked"  where IsClicked is a component property and you can add and remove class based on this property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add one variable `selected` in your component and use it with [NgClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) to add `active` class.

**Component:**

```
public selected: string = '';

public function navChanged (child: string){
    this.selected = child
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li *ngFor="let child of children">
  <a (click)="navChanged(child.name)" [ngClass]="{'active' : child.name === selected}">
    <div> {{child.name}} </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for properly editing my question, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check below examples

```
<li *ngFor="let child of children">
  <a (click)="navChanged(child.name)">
    <div [ngClass]="{active: isActive(n)}"> {{child.name}} </div>
  </a>
</li>

  navChanged(item) {
      this.selected = item; 
  };
  isActive(item) {
      return this.selected === item;
  };
```

**Only using html**

```
<li *ngFor="let child of children">
  <a (click)="navChanged(child.name);clicked = (clicked === n ? null :n)">
    <div [class.active]="clicked === n" > {{child.name}} </div>
  </a>
</li>
```